# Move through rows in R

Tags: r

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 0 | 4 |

I have a column "value1" in a data frame and I want to repeat the same value until the next number > 0. What i want as a result is the column "value2". It is a big amount of data so a loop code would be great.

Thanks to the community!!

Comment: If the non-zero values always increase, like in your example, use `cummax`. If not, replace 0 with `NA`, and use one of the many LOCF methods.

Comment: Please clarify if you can have more than one consecutive non-zero value. If so, answers based on `cumsum` won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `cumsum` with the condition:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(value2 = cumsum(value1>0))
```

```
   value1 value2
1       1      1
2       0      1
3       0      1
4       0      1
5       2      2
6       0      2
7       0      2
8       3      3
9       4      4
10      0      4
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(value1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works just fine

Answer (score 1):

#### Using data.table & comparison with base and dplyr

##### data.table method

This is a data.table based version of the answer which is quicker than both the base and dplyr versions.

```r
set.seed(65L)
df <- data.table(v1 = sample(0:4, 1000, replace = TRUE), v2 = 0)
df[, v2 := cumsum(v1 > 0)]
head(df, 12)
    v1 v2
 1:  2  1
 2:  1  2
 3:  3  3
 4:  0  3
 5:  0  3
 6:  4  4
 7:  2  5
 8:  4  6
 9:  4  7
10:  0  7
11:  4  8
12:  2  9
```

##### Three-method comparison: equivalence

```r
set.seed(65L)
df <- data.frame(v1 = sample(0:4, 1000, replace = TRUE), v2 = 0)
df2 <- df
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# data.table
dt[, v2 := cumsum(v1 > 0)]

# base R
if (df$v1[1L] > 0) {df$v2[1L] <- 1}
for (i in 2:length(df$v1)) {
  df$v2[i] <- df$v2[i - 1] + if (df$v1[i] > 0) {1} else {0}
}

# dplyr
if (df2$v1[1L] > 0) {df2$v2[1L] <- 1}
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(v2 = cumsum(v1>0))

all.equal(dt, df, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
all.equal(dt, df2, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
all.equal(df, df2, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

##### Three-method comparison: speed

```r
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(DT = dt[, v2 := cumsum(v1 > 0)],
Base = {if (df$v1[1L] > 0) {df$v2[1L] <- 1};for (i in 2:length(df$v1)) {df$v2[i] <- df$v2[i - 1] + if (df$v1[i] > 0) {1} else {0}}},
DP = {if (df2$v1[1L] > 0) {df2$v2[1L] <- 1};df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(v2 = cumsum(v1>0))},
setup = 'set.seed(65L);df <- data.table(v1 = sample(0:4, 1000, replace = TRUE), v2 = 0); df2 <- df; dt <- as.data.table(df)',
control = list(order = 'block'), times = 1000L)

Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq      mean median      uq     max neval cld
   DT  204.1  210.20  216.6067  212.0  216.80   382.9  1000 a  
 Base 7956.1 8322.85 8936.3439 8457.6 8702.25 22219.4  1000   c
   DP  916.0  930.50  994.4782  939.8  977.60  6157.4  1000  b
```

So the `dplyr` method is about 9 times faster than the base loop and the `data.table` method is about 4.5 times faster than `dplyr` and over 40 times faster than base!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For these cases I typically replace the 0s with `NA` values, and use `tidyr::fill()` to copy the last non-missing (i.e. non-zero) value forward.

Here is an example:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  value1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0)
) 


library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    value2 = ifelse(value1 == 0, NA_real_, value1)
  ) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(value2, .direction = "down")
```

and the result:

```r
   value1 value2
1       1      1
2       0      1
3       0      1
4       0      1
5       2      2
6       0      2
7       0      2
8       3      3
9       4      4
10      0      4
```

This works even when the values are increasing by more/less than 1, which is not the case with e.g. `cumsum()`.

Comment: I did not know this aproach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No need for using a loop. One option using `base` R would be:

```
df <- data.frame(value1 = c(1,0,0,0,2,0,0,3,4,0))
df$value2 <- cumsum(ifelse(df$value1 > 0, 1, 0))
```

Which yields:

```
> df
   value1 value2
1       1      1
2       0      1
3       0      1
4       0      1
5       2      2
6       0      2
7       0      2
8       3      3
9       4      4
10      0      4
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Base R

There may be more elegant ways to do this but assuming that the column "value2" is already in the dataframe you can do something like the following. This answer relies solely on base R and also it does not matter if v1 is increasing or decreasing, just that it is non-zero. I'll create a data frame as an example.

```r
set.seed(65L)
df <- data.frame(v1 = sample(0:4, 1000, replace = TRUE), v2 = 0)
 
head(df, 12)
   v1 v2
1   2  0
2   1  0
3   3  0
4   0  0
5   0  0
6   4  0
7   2  0
8   4  0
9   4  0
10  0  0
11  4  0
12  2  0
 
# Handle the first row seperately to get rid of i - 1 headaches
if (df$v1[1L] > 0) {df$v2[1L] <- 1}
 
# Now the loop. Safer to do seq_len(length(df$v1) - 1) + 1 but that's more confusing
 
for (i in 2:length(df$v1)) {
    df$v2[i] <- df$v2[i - 1] + if (df$v1[i] > 0) {1} else {0}
}
 
head(df, 12)
   v1 v2
1   2  1
2   1  2
3   3  3
4   0  3
5   0  3
6   4  4
7   2  5
8   4  6
9   4  7
10  0  7
11  4  8
12  2  9
```

Comment: Using `for` loops to iterate over rows is inefficient in a sense that it is relatively time consuming, especially for large data sets with many rows.

Comment: Yes, but it is much faster than it used to be and dplyr is not optimized for speed.  On my laptop this took 9 milliseconds on 1000 rows. I cannot really compare with the other methods since they will fail if the first entry is 0.

Comment: True that, one of the reasons for using `base` R. But what if you have to iterate over 10,000,000+ rows and execute something more complex than in the OP's case?

Comment: Sure, which is why I said it wasn't elegant, but it would get the job done. If we really needed to optimize for speed, a `data.table` rolling sum approach would be best, I think.

Comment: @Dion I posted a data.table version in a new answer as per the top answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice and provided speed statistics below. dplyr is around 9 times faster than base and data.table over 40 times faster.